# Manipulate return values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert decimal degrees to degrees, minutes and seconds using the following code:

```
def dd2dms(deg):
    d = int(deg)
    md = abs(deg - d) * 60
    m = int(md)
    sd = (md - m) * 60
    return [d, m, sd]

full = 500/60
print(full)
print(dd2dms(full))
```

But I get the following output:

```
8.333333333333334 [8, 20, 0]
```

I would like to get the output as:

```
8.333333333333334 8:20:0
```

How can I achieve this? I am taking baby steps in learning Python. :)

Answer (score 1):

If it is just for display purposes something like:

```
print("{0}:{1}:{2}".format(*dd2dms(full)))
```

Comment: one more missing ) has been added and it works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little class built around your angle that has a conversion function for dms and also a nicely formatted string representation:

```
class Angle(float):
    def __init__(self, degrees):
        self.degrees = degrees

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Angle of {}° ({})>".format(self.degrees, self.dms)            

    @property
    def dms(self):
        deg = self.degrees
        d = int(deg)
        md = abs(deg - d) * 60
        m = int(md)
        sd = (md - m) * 60
        return "{:g}:{:g}:{:g}".format(d, m, sd)
```

Demo:

```
In[1]: a = Angle(90.173)
In[2]: print(a)
90.173
In[3]: print(a.dms)
90:10:22.8
In[4]: a
Out[4]: <Angle of 90.173° (90:10:22.8)>
```

Since it inherits from float, you can even calculate with it. Note though that the return value will be a normal float (not an `Angle`) without further adaption of the class.

Answer (score 0):

If `dd2dms` returns an array, you just need to extract the array elements, convert them to strings and then concatenate. If you're just beginning to learn Python, try something easy like this:

```
result = dd2dms(full)
print(str(result[0]) + ":" + str(result[1]) + ":" + str(result[2]))
```

where `result[i]` returns the `i`-th element of array `result`, `str()` constructs a string from its argument, and then you can just concatenate the strings with `+`.

Comment: @Python_newbie Please consider upvoting answers that help and accepting an answer which best answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove square brackets from return statement (to return a tuple instead a list):

```py
return d, m, sd
```

and format output string:

```py
"%s:%s:%s" % dd2dms(full)
```

Full snippet:

```py
def dd2dms(deg):
    d = int(deg)
    md = abs(deg - d) * 60
    m = int(md)
    sd = (md - m) * 60
    return d, m, sd

full = 500/60
print(full)
print("%s:%s:%s" % dd2dms(full))
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.6 you can use use literal string interpolation https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/ to do the following:

```
def dd2dms(deg):
    d = int(deg)
    md = abs(deg - d) * 60
    m = int(md)
    sd = (md - m) * 60
    return f'{d}:{m}:{sd}'
```

You can even do computations in the strings

for instance, you could do :

```
def dd2dms(deg):
    d = int(deg)
    md = abs(deg - d) * 60
    m = int(md)
    return f'{d}:{m}:{(md - m) * 60}'
```

However, it's usually better to declare your variables explicitly.